# PHP Strings not equal when they are

Tags: php, md5

I've got this code here to check if a password is correct in my login script;

```
if(md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($pwd) == $row['password']))
```

Echoing both of these values, they're the exact same, except my script runs the else statement which tells the user the password is incorrect rather than actually logging them in.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: using `md5` is not a good idea at all. instead of use `password-hashing`.As well as a bracket is missing too:- `if(md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($pwd)) == $row['password'])) `

Comment: Why do you call `md5()` 3 times?

Comment: Using multiple md5s will just increase clash rates and doesn't make it anymore secure

Comment: You're calling `md5()` on the result of `==`. That's not very useful, and it will always be true. You need to fix your parenthesis grouping.

Comment: Match Brackets : `if(md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($pwd)) == $row['password'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($pwd) == $row['password']))
```

Questioning the use of md5 and using multiple md5 invocations, you're doing something weird here.

```
md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($pwd) == $row['password'])
```

is the contents of your IF statement. You're asking IF (md5 result of a comparison!!).

```
if (md5(1=1))
```

is not what you want, I assume.